# Which Open Source Cloud Management Platform supports Amazon-RDS?

Tags: cloud, amazon-rds, eucalyptus, rightscale, opennebula

I have been trying to use Amazon Web services, specially EC2 and [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/). Nowadays most CMP (Cloud Management Platform) like [Eucalyptus](http://www.eucalyptus.com/aws-compatibility), [OpenNebula](http://opennebula.org/documentation%3aarchives%3arel2.0%3aec2qec), [OpenStack](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/devref/api.html), [Nimbus](http://www.nimbusproject.org/docs/2.10.1/elclients.html) and [CloudStack](http://cloudstack.apache.org/docs/api/index.html) all support Ec2 to a certain level, some do it better than others.

But when it comes to Amazon's RDS service I just can't seem to find any information. It's like no CMP supports it. On my research I came across a website that suggests the use of third-party software like [HybridFox](http://code.google.com/p/hybridfox/), [RightScale](http://www.rightscale.com/) [enStratus](http://www.enstratius.com/) to have an RDS like support but I don't get it.

Can someone tell me if Eucalyptus, OpenNebula, OpenStack, Nimbus and CloudStack support RDS?

If not, then how I can I use third-party software to access Amazon's RDS service using the previously mentioned CMPs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RDS is a proprietary technology from Amazon. The equivalent Database as a Service in OpenStack is project Red Dwarf - https://wiki.openstack.org/wiki/Reddwarf  which is implemented as Cloud Databases at Rackspace (for MySQL)

Comment: Thanks, that deserves karma++. 
I am not emailing openNebula and Eucalyptus for answers, but I am not confident tbh. I would really like to see their solutions to this problem because in my opinion both beat OpenSTack :P